# how to set search parameter in google-api-ruby-client

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

in order to retrieve the contents of a folder I have to use the following url
    https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='root'
so I thought it should be working by passing an additional parameter

```
    @client.execute(
    :api_method => @drive.files.list ,
    :parameters =>{q=> "title='root'" })
```

But this does not work

An error occurred: {"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"invalid", "message"=>"Invalid Value", "locationType"=>"parameter", "location"=>"q"}], "code"=>400, "message"=>"Invalid Value"}

This is pretty obvious when I see the request uri

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title%253D%27levelA%27
```

My first attempt was to user URI.encode "title='root'" which does not work neither.
I really dont know how I could keep the single quotes ?

Best,
Philip

p.s.: a link to the mentioned gem http://rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/frames

Answer (score 1):

ok, now I found a working solution, even though it is a very cumbersome one.

```
search = CGI.escape("q='root'")
u.query = search
u= Addressable::URI.parse "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files"
req=Google::APIClient::Request.new(:uri=> u)
client.execute req
```

I hope this helps someone..